# Delphi: How to use Open XML Word SDK

Tags: ms-word, openxml

How can I use Microsoft's Open XML SDK API from Delphi?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing?view=openxml-2.8.1

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft’s Open XML SDK is a .NET library:

1. It provides strongly-typed classes to manipulate documents that adhere to the Office Open XML File Formats specification
2. However, it does not have a COM implementation and does not export COM info, which means it cannot be directly used from Delphi, which is a native code language.

If you want to use .NET libraries from Delphi, you would typically need to create a .NET COM wrapper